# What is the information-theoretical lower bound for estimating $E[f(X)]$

Tags: estimation, convergence, information-theory, mutual-information

Given i.i.d. realizations $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ of a random variable $X$, what is the information-theoretical lower bound of the convergence rate for estimating $E[f(X)]$? Here $f$ is a function from $[0,1]$ to $[0,1]$.

If $f$ is identity, then this becomes the problem of estimating the mean. We can use Gaussian mean model as the worst case to establish a $1/\sqrt{n}$ lower bound on the convergence rate in absolute value. I am not sure how to establish this lower bound for general $f$.

Comment: If $f$ is identity, it is not a function from $\mathbb R$ to $[0,1]$, generally speaking.

Comment: @cardinal Thanks. I have fixed the input domain :)

Comment: Sorry for the pedantry, but, implicitly, $X: \Omega \to [0,1]$, then? Such a restriction may materially affect the kind of answer you receive.

Comment: @cardinal For example $X$ is the uniform distribution on $[0,1]$.

Comment: Are you willing to put any smoothness constraints on $f$?  Unless $f$ is at least (uniformly?) continuous, I don't think we'll get very far.

Comment: @AndrewM Yes I think we can assume $f$ is in some smoothness class.

Comment: Can you confirm that you are indeed interested in $E(f(X))$ and not $E(f(X) | X)$?  I don't think there's anything very interesting to say (beyond the Law of Large Numbers) about the convergence of $1/N \sum_i f(X_i)$ to $E(f(X))$ if $f$ is known, or alternately if $Y_i=f(X_i)$ is observed.

Comment: Yes indeed I am interested in $E(f(X))$. If $f$ is monotone, then it is an one-to-one mapping, we can just use $Y_i = f(X_i)$ instead. However, once $f$ is not one-to-one, from the data processing inequality point of view (which is used in, for example, fano's inequality), there is loss of information. So the estimation should become harder?